# Selenium Grid support for Selenium 2?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have read that Selenium Grid support was planned for Selenium 2.0 at the year end - 2010. Apparently it has not happened. Anyone knows of any updates on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the talks at the [Selenium Conference](http://www.seleniumconf.com/) this weekend talked about Selenium Grid 2.  It is on track and will be released with Selenium 2, including the next Beta (Beta 4).  It is going to  be more robust than Grid 1.  In fact the hope is that it replaces RC, which would essentially become a grid of 1.  You can read about it in the fifth paragraph of [this blog post covering the conference](http://mkl-testhead.blogspot.com/2011/04/selenium-conference-day-3-ongoing.html).

Answer (score 4):

Selenium Grid 2 supports Selenium 2 and is backward compatible with Selenium 1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Selnium Grid will support Selenium 2.x, check http://seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) of using selenium 2.0 and WebDriver