# how to run more than one selenium tests on different browsers at the same time

Tags: selenium

I am running these 3 test cases on selenium IDE , they are running fine , but are running sequentially , I want to run all of these 3 tests at the same time on different browsers , How can i achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that there is [Selenium Grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

See this topic for support for Selenium 2: [Selenium Grid support for Selenium 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581410/selenium-grid-support-for-selenium-2)